# Force SSRS Report to create a file rather than render on screen

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Using SSRS for SS 2008, is there a way to force the report to download rather than render?  I have a report that has thousands of rows - rather than waste resources returning the resultset to the front end, I would rather just force the user to download a CSV or XLS file.

This is not a subscription-based report - rather, it is adhoc via a "click".

Comment: What do you mean by "a click"? Are you utilizing the ReportViewer? In a web environment?

Comment: Read this article [link](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/115/posts/11164/refreshable-ssrs-reports-in-excel.aspx) it will help your problem.

Comment: Outside of the report viewer web control's export functions, you can export to any supported format programmatically using Url and/or ws api access.

Answer (score 3):

I think exporting using url might be your solution. Try the following :

`http://localhost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSample+Report+Solution+R+and+D%2fGroupWise+Report&rs:Format=CSV`

Comment: +1 @GilPeretz. Couple this with a batch or vbscript to automatically download and save  the file to a directory and you've got a 1-click operation if you don't care what is in the report (ie doing for someone else)