# Wait for reportviewer to render before continuing

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer, reporting-services

I am trying to create some SSRS reports inside a loop, the report should render onscreen, then save to a file, then update a list box to say it has been saved.
I have managed to get the reports rendering inside the loop, updating the list box and saving, the problem is that the report never displays onscreen until after the last report has been ran at which point last last report magically appears!  I *think* that the problem is that I am not waiting on the report to render before continuing back round the loop again (Although I'm not sure as surely the report must be rendered in order to save it?).  How do I wait until the report has been rendered before continuing on to the next step in the loop?

Comment: When you say `Saving` do you mean that the report exported in some format ? or saved as RDL file ?

Comment: I export the report to a PDF file, this works fine. But before the export I want to render the report in the report viewer (so the user can see the repot has been rendered). If I put in something like reportview.refresh(); then messagebox.show(""); the report renders OK, the user clicks OK then the loop starts again. But I dont want to have a messagebox I want it all to run automatically and just flash up the rendered report for a second or so

Answer (score 0):

I think its better for you to run the process parallel.

Means that you can export the report to PDF without render it on screen, and in parallel render it for user's view.

[Force SSRS Report to create a file rather than render on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591878/force-ssrs-report-to-create-a-file-rather-than-render-on-screen/14592132#14592132)

Comment: I dont suppose the user actually needs to see it, it will be running on a server to print out documents automatically, was just wanting to show it on screen as it may be usefull if anything went wrong with the process to see what it was doing.

Comment: Oh I see, so maybe a nice workaround that you can do is to present a preview of the PDF